# Sumar el total del costo de los ultimos 12 meses por cada mes SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

yo tengo un problema y es que quiero general un consulta en SQL que me permita obtener el valor de la sumatoria del costo de los ultimos 12 meses (1 año) pero por cada mes, es decir que en enero de 2021 me muestre la sumatoria desde enero de 2021 hasta febrero de 2020, que en febrero de 2021 me muestre el total desde febrero de 2021 hasta marzo de 2020 y así sucesivamente.

como pueden ver en la imagen tengo ya los datos pero como los he agrupado por categoría, mes y año, evidentemente me muestra solo el total del mes y no la sumatoria de todo el año de cada categoría

[image: Ejemplo]

Answer (score 0):

Si entiendo bien lo que quieres es el total por mes y año

Debes poder lograrlo con "Group by" puedes especificar más de una columna para agrupar.

Ejemplo

```
Select año, mes, SUM(TotalVenta) venta_mes
From Ventas
Where año =2014
Group by año,mes
```

El Where lo acomodas de acuerdo a tus necesidades, si necesitas todos los años no incluyas la cláusula `Where`

Comment: Si, asi mas o menos lo tengo el detalles es que no quiero el valor de 1 solo año sino que de todos los que estan en la base de datos

Comment: Entonces elimina el Where y obtendrás de todos los años

Answer (score 0):

Para cada mes y año esta query suma el total de ventas del mes, y el total de ventas del último año.

```
SELECT v1.Mes, v1.Anio, MIN(v1.TotalVentas) AS TotalVentasMes, SUM(v2.TotalVentas) AS TotalVentasUltimoAnio

FROM

(SELECT Mes, Anio, dateadd(year, -1, datefromparts(Anio, Mes, 1)) AS FechaDesde, 
      datefromparts(Anio, Mes, 1) as FechaHasta, SUM(TotalVenta) AS TotalVentas
  FROM Ventas
  GROUP BY Mes, Anio) AS v1
  
INNER JOIN (SELECT Mes, Anio, datefromparts(Anio, Mes, 1) AS Fecha, SUM(TotalVenta) AS TotalVentas
  FROM Ventas
  GROUP BY Mes, Anio) AS v2 ON v2.Fecha > v1.FechaDesde AND v2.Fecha <= v1.FechaHasta

GROUP BY v1.Mes, v1.Anio

ORDER BY v1.Anio, v1.Mes
```